# Adjoint map of product Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let us consider the product $G \times H$ of two Lie groups $G$ and $H$.
The elements of such Lie groups are $(g,h)\in G\times H$, $g\in G$, and $h\in H$, respectively.

Is the adjoint map of the product group given by the product of the each adjoint map? In other words, does it hold
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{(g,h)} = (\operatorname{Ad}_g,\operatorname{Ad}_h)
$$
?

Comment: Do you mean adjoint map $\operatorname{Ad}\colon G\longrightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(\frak g)$, where $\frak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$?

Comment: No, I mean the map $Ad_g: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$

Comment: Actually, I believe that that “no” is a “yes”. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $(g,h)\in G\times H$, let $\Psi_{G\times H}(g,h)\colon G\times H\longrightarrow G\times H$ be the map\begin{align}(g',h')\mapsto(g,h)(g',h')(g,h)^{-1}&=(gg'g^{-1},hh'h^{-1})\\&=\bigl(\Psi_G(g)(g'),\Psi_H(h)(h')\bigr).\end{align}Then$$\bigl(\mathrm d\Psi_{G\times H}(g,h)\bigr)_{e_{G\times H}}\colon\frak g\times\frak h\longrightarrow\frak g\times\frak h$$is the map defined by$$(X,Y)\mapsto\bigl((d\Psi_G(g)_{e_G}(X),(d\Psi_H(h)_{e_H}(Y)\bigr).\tag1$$But $\bigl(\mathrm d\Psi_{G\times H}(g,h)\bigr)_{e_{G\times H}}=\operatorname{Ad}_{(g,h)}$ and $(1)$ is $(\operatorname{Ad}_g,\operatorname{Ad}_h)$.

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was looking for. However, I suspect there are two typos in (1), which should be:$$(X,Y)\mapsto\bigl((d\Psi_G(g)_{e_G}(X),(d\Psi_H(h)_{e_H}(Y)\bigr).$$ Do you agree?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$Ad_{(g,h)}(x,y)=(g,h)(x,y)(g,h)^{-1}=(g,h)(x,y)(g^{-1},h^{-1})=(gxg^{-1},hyh^{-1})=(Ad_g(x),Ad_h(y))$

Comment: (x,y) is an element of the Lie algebra of $G\times H$, whereas $(g,h)$ is an element of $G\times H$. In the product you used, there's a Lie group elements times a Lie algebra element times a Lie group element. How is the product operation that you used defined? I am confused because I am only aware of product operation between Lie group elements, and not between Lie group elements and Lie algebra elements.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Your formula holds for the particular case of _matrix_ Lie groups. In this case, the matrix product is used for writing your formula.